# Error Occuring when publishing changes in WAS 7.0 using RAD 7.5.5

Tags: websphere

I am using WAS 7.0 with RAD 7.5.5. I have created an EAR project the problem is whenever I restart RAD or Refresh projects the publishing on WAS takes infinite amount of time and the error message below is dispayed-

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.impl.ApplicationImpl
>   incompatible with org.eclipse.jst.javaee.application.Application

I have tried cleaning the project, also tried deleting the project and changing the workspace but after some time this error comes again and again.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Software Support should be able to help you.  Just open a PMR.

Comment: That's not the idea here, I'm having the same issue, would love to see here a real solution, rather than pointing me to support that I don't have true access to.

Comment: Why don't you have true access?  That's why you have commercial software.

Comment: The IBM support is within our organization channeled through a limited number of people, whom I don't want to drop an issue on that is only just the fruit of me exploring some possible directions.